# KroneckerDelta in matlab

Tags: matlab, delta

[This link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/kroneckerdelta.html) shows that there is a kronecker delta function in matlab.  However:

```
>> help kroneckerDelta

    kroneckerDelta not found
```

I am using R2011b, so maybe this wasn't programmed into the toolkit yet?

EDIT:: It works in MuPad, just not in matlab...

.

Comment: Also for future reference, you would have to check your version documentation as you may note that link provides R2013a documentation (so do all searches). So try from the Mathworks >> Support >> Documentation Center >> Other Release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it in my R2012b so perhaps not. Unless you need the symbolic math, you could always write your own. Something as simple as

```
function d = kronDel(j,k)

if j == k
    d = 1;
else
    d = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The Kronecker delta returns 1 if j==k...

So you could simplify the expression with:

```
function d=kronDel(j,k)

d=j==k

end
```

Luckily, MATLAB represents booleans as (0,1)

Comment: You should format your code. Also, this question is tagged [matlab], not [octave], so `end` should be used. It would probably also be a good idea to cast the output to `double` or the class of the input variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this inline, like

```
( a == b )
```

However, using an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?refresh=true) is a nice way to convert a one liner like this into something that is more readable

```
kronDel = @(j, k) j==k ;

kronDel( 2, 1 )
kronDel( 2, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link to is to the [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) function `kroneckerDelta` -note the URL and the funky typography of the examples. You won't see it in *any* version of Matlab because it's only available through MuPAD (type `mupad` in your command window and try in the window that launches). I have no idea when it was added to MuPAD, I know that it's at least in R2012b. You may have it even if the `help` command returns nothing.

If you have `kroneckerDelta` in R2011b, you won't be able to run it from the regular command window or Editor in the normal fashion.

```
evalin(symengine,'kroneckerDelta(1,1)')
```

or the more flexible

```
feval(symengine,'kroneckerDelta',1,1)
```

See [more here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html). However, if you're not working with symbolic math, there's really no reason to use this function that I can see -it's not even vectorized! I'd go with a solution that fully emulates `kroneckerDelta`'s behavior in double precision:

```
function d=kronDel(m,n)
if nargin == 1
    d = double(m==0);
else
    d = double(m==n);
end
```

Comment: ...just saw your edit about it working in MuPAD. Well, here's the rest of the story...